# ECS Cluster: Getting tasks in different services to run on different EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS Cluster on which i have configured 3 different Services (let's say svc1, svc2, svc3).

I would like do make sure the tasks/containers of each service are run on EC2 instances that are not running tasks/containers of the other two services.

I have read the documentation about [task placement contraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html) and about [task groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-groups.html) and I understood is that when a task created by a service it automatically gets a task group with the same name of the service.

So what I configured on each of my 3 services (in the service itself, not in the task definition) is the following placement constraint:

> Type: memberOf
> Expression: task:group != service:svc2 and task:group != service:svc3

On each service I would exclude the other two.

This configuration doesn't seem to work though as I get two behaviours:

- When I turn on my EC2 instances and all the services try to start together none of them are able to start tasks and give the following error:

> service svc1 was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 3d9d2d497fc9489ab26551475f4d7025 encountered error "MemberOf placement constraint unsatisfied.". For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.

- Then I tested removing the placement contraints on 2 services and keeping it only on 1. When I do a new deployment of the tasks (done with CodeDeploy, with Blue/Green deployment) they just end up running all together on the same container instance (I have more than 1 container instances up and configured in ECS)

I'm really not understanding how this is supposed to work and if I'm missing something or it's just bad documentation.

Comment: hey there, have you tried the constraint as `not(task:group == service:svcX)` instead? ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-query-language.html#expression-examples

Comment: Thank you @marianogg9 it really was the wrong syntax! Using not() instead of != successfully deployes the tasks on different instances!
Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-query-language.html#expression-examples), the way of specifying a negative match is `not(task:group == database)` -> in your case it would be `not(task:group == service:svcX)`.

Hope it helps!